# Regular expression: data between brackets (mysqli > pdo)

Tags: regex

For migrating a system to PDO, we would like to replace some queries. Via a regular expression, we can improve the progress. We are looking for a method to match:

```
mysqli_query($db, [expression follows here])
```

So, we made use of the following regex:

```
mysqli_query\(\$db, (.*?)\)
```

The problem is that we've a problem when we have for example a join query with an opening and closing () parameter.

Example: `mysqli_query($db, "SELECT users.id FROM users JOIN (... ) on .. WHERE users.id=1")`

Is it possible to edit the regex so we allow a ) when it is opened? So, the number of ( and ) should be equal.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do that in a code editor? If so, which one? Or programmatically (if so, which language)? Also, can we be sure that there won't be any parentheses within comments or strings etc. that could trip up the regex?

Comment: No, just the regular expression. So, I need an expression that return all the data between ', ' and ')' even the opening and closing ( & ).

Comment: OK, but which regex engine? Not many support recursion which we need here.

Comment: "when we have for example a join query with an opening and closing () parameter. Is it possible to edit the regex so we allow a ) when it is opened? " - You should post an example...

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew that. Well, I do use dreamweaver, but we can use every software which is available for the max (e.g. text editor, textwrangler etc.)

Comment: Example: mysqli_query($db, "SELECT users.id FROM users JOIN (... ) on .. WHERE users.id=1"). (the opening and closing " are not always the case, could also be $query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an editor with PCRE-compatible regexes (Dreamweaver probably only supports JavaScript-style regexes); then you can use a recursive regex like this:

```
mysqli_query\(\$db, ((?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*)\)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iM0Wbn/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(          # Match and capture in group 1:
 (?:       # Start of non-capturing group that either matches  
  [^()]++  # a sequence of characters except parentheses
 |         # or 
 \(        # an opening parenthesis
  (?1)     # followed by an expression that follows the same rules as group 1
 \)        # and a closing parenthesis. 
 )*        # Do this any number of times (including 0)
)          # End of group 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `mysqli_query\(\$db, ('|")(.+?)\1\)[\s;]`. This assumes that the expression will be between single or double quotes. This might fail depending on what content comes after it though, and for some notations within the SQL query itself (e.g. if it encounters `\')`).

https://regex101.com/r/1NRYUw/1

Comment: One of the comments states that you can't rely on the presence of quotes.